# Tor and Orbot not working in Ethiopia

Tags: censorship

The only ISP in Ethiopia (government owned) has been trying so hard to silence and disconnect bloggers, journalists and activists from the world ever since the current dictatorship came to power. Around May 2012 they blocked Tor and made the use of VoIP services like Skype regulated (in some cases illegal). Because of the monopoly, telephone costs are expensive and millions of us have been relying on VoIP services to communicate with and do businesses. Unfortunately as of April 2016 they completely blocked VoIP services and apps like Skype, Viber, Facebook, Whatsapp Messenger and many more because of the decreased revenue. Now I am not a blogger an activist or a political person. I am a good citizen who wants to work and contribute to my society. I am working on a big research and been communicating with scientists abroad and here via Skype and Whatsapp. The government's current actions have created immense pressure on our jobs. The only way of communication has become email and phone calls which is not enough. So me and my friends tried Tor via Bridges and Orbot on our phones. Most bridges are not working and the only bridge that worked on Orbot got blocked the next day. Dear people of the free world please let us know what we can do to connect to the world and do our jobs. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you use plain bridges or pluggable transports (obfs4, fte etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you enable the Obfs4 or "Tunnel through..." Meek bridge option in Orbot? There are built in Obfs4 bridges now with the latest release of Orbot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a Tor directory is being queried by censors, so try to obtain a private bridges that don't publish their descriptors and use a pluggable transports like OBFS3/4 or Meek

Answer (score 0):

You should configure TOR with **Meek**. It is a pluggable transport designed to bypass circumvention by your ISP. The latest version of TOR already has **meek client** in-built.